# How use Flutter syncfusion calendar with jalali date

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying to develop calendar like this https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_calendar but I don't know how to use this package for Jalali date (Persian date).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can create your custom one which I think it is the best way

as you can see [here](https://github.com/syncfusion/flutter-examples/issues/95)

for now there is no way to use Persian(jalali) calendar with syncfusion,

here is what they have said about
.

> As of now, we don’t have support for converting the calendar to jalali
> calendar. We have logged the feature request for the same. We will
> implement it in any of our upcoming releases. We appreciate your
> patience until then

but you can make its language to farsi(only language and not the calendar time) with loocalization

```
MaterialApp(
            //ignore: always_specify_types
      localizationsDelegates: [
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        // ... app-specific localization delegate[s] here
        SfGlobalLocalizations.delegate
      ],
      //ignore: always_specify_types
      supportedLocales: const [
        Locale('en'),
        Locale('fa'),
        // ... other locales the app supports
      ],
      locale: const Locale('fa'),
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
        home: MyHomePage(),
    );
```

again, it just changes the language